# MacVim: Files outside of the home directory cannot be opened from the command line unless full path is specified

Tags: macvim

I'm trying to open a file using MacVim 7.3 (53) from the command line using the bash shell in the Terminal system application in OS X 10.6.6. Files specified as command line arguments to MacVim are always opened from the home folder. For example:

```
> cd ~
> cd somefolder
> MacVim somefile.txt
```

This results in the file **~/somefile.txt** being opened instead of **~/somefolder/somefile.txt**.

If the full path to the file is specified in the command line argument the file will be opened as expected. For example:

```
> cd ~
> MacVim ~/somefolder/somefile.txt
```

Setting the option **autochdir** in **.vimrc** does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mvim` command line shell script to execute MacVim from command line. Just tested and it works as expected.

Comment: I don't see that script in the MacVim.app folder. Can you post your script?